# SQL function to determine if a field has changed

Tags: sql

I have a status table that has three datetime fields that get updated by a service.
Does SQL have any built in functions that can tell me if a field has been updated?.
Thanks.

Comment: "SQL" isn't a DBMS.  What DBMS are you using?

Comment: you can use a trigger.

Comment: SQL Server: Search for [change tracking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: An update trigger would be invoked any time a record is updated, and within the trigger you would have access to pre- and post-update values so you can perform whatever logic you want accordingly.

Comment: As @TechGirl you can use a trigger that looks up for UPDATE sentences and if there is one you can then do an INSERT in a table that gives you information such as the date of change, field changed, previous and after value of the field.

Comment: "SQL" is just a query language, not a specific DBMS product. What you are asking is **highly** DBMS specific. So which database product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 developer edition.

Comment: The trigger works for me, many thanks.